# trying to change logo on image gallery based on light or dark image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image gallery on the home page which is using this plugin:

http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-slider-zoom-inout-effect-fully-responsive/2457203

My client wants to have a lighter logo for darker images and a darker logo for lighter images. I'm pretty comfortable with jQuery, but have never had to do something like this.

This is the effect they're looking for:

http://www.aplusi.com/

I know on this site, they're adding a class (dark-slide) to the body and then using a more specific class:

```
.dark-slide #logo {
    color: #fff;
}
```

to get the logo to change from black to white. My only problem is I don't know *how* they're doing it since it also works with their swipe functionality as well. I've dug into their JS but can't seem to find the code.

I have a few ideas like having a click handler on the arrows to check what image is presented and then add the necessary class. The only problem with this is that the gallery has a swipe functionality and jQuery doesn't have an event handler for touch events.

My other thought was to have an interval timer and then add the class onto the necessary image at the right time - this is something I haven't done and wouldn't know where to start.

I'm thinking this should be fairly easy, but I can't seem to come up with a decent solution so I thought I would ask.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Their JavaScript is obfuscated unfortunately, but the code you are looking for is this (which funnily enough seems to be missing a semicolon):

```
var u = e.Color.getBrightness(o.getAttribute("data-top-right-color"));    
e.one(document.body).toggleClass("dark-slide", u < 35)
```

"data-top-right-color" is an attribute set individually on each slide. Every time the slide changes, the function containing the above code fires and checks that *data-* attribute to see if it should add the "dark-slide" class to make the logo font white.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a container for the image which is active. To change the logo as per the image prsent in the slider, you have 2 options:

1. Maintain some attribute in the `img` tag so that you can diffrentiate as per the value of the attribute. Eg. `<img src='image.png' data-value='dark'>`
2. If you are unable to maintain the attribute then a complex solution will be to write an algo to determine the type of active image **Using canvas**

To change the logo:

```
var logoImg=$('#logo');
if(activeImgType=='dark')
{
    logoImg.attr('light.png');
}else{
    logoImg.attr('dark.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get it done. It uses a canvas for processing the image. The concept is based on detecting whether the image is dark or light using a grayscale version of the original image.

Here's is a working [version](http://jsbin.com/musecosohi/edit?html,output) based on background color of a div.
If you want to use images as background, please refer my code [here](https://github.com/KunjanThadani/canvasTextColor). I have uploaded a sample with the background images. I couldn't produce a fiddle or online demo because of cross origin problems.

The code for simple rgb backgrounds is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dynamic text color demo using canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label><b>Image with text</b></label>
    <div id="content" style="box-shadow:0px 0px 1px #000;width:200px;height:100px;background-color:#333;">
    <b style="z-index:2;position:absolute;color:black !important;">BLACK Text</b>

    <br><b style="z-index:2;position:absolute;color:white !important;">WHITE Text</b>
    <br><b style="z-index:2;position:absolute;color:rgb(127,127,127) !important;">GRAY Text</b>
    <br><b style="z-index:2;position:absolute">CORRECTED COLOR</b>  
    </div><br><br>
    <label><b>Variables</b></label>
    <div id="height">

    </div>
    <div id="width">
    </div>
    <div id="dataLength">

    </div>
    <div id="blackCount">

    </div>
    <br>
    <label><b>Canvas for grayscale</b></label><br>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200px" height="100px" style="box-shadow:0px 0px 1px #000"></canvas>
      <script>

          /* ~~~~~ This function loops over various images ~~~~~ */
            var c=0;
          var color;
          function loop(){
                c++;
                document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundColor='rgb('+(c*29)%255+','+(c*29)%255+','+(c*29)%255+')';
                var imageObj = new Image();
                imageObj.onload = function() {
                drawImage(color);
           }

          color=document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundColor;
          var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var x = 0;
          var y = 0;

          context.rect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
          context.fillStyle='rgb('+(c*29)%255+','+(c*29)%255+','+(c*29)%255+')';
          context.fill();

          /* ~~~~~ Print height and widht of image ~~~~~ */
          document.getElementById('height').innerHTML="height: "+imageObj.height;
          document.getElementById('width').innerHTML="width: "+imageObj.width;
          /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

          var imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          var data = imageData.data;

          /* ~~~~~ This part converts the image to grayscale ~~~~~ */
              for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
              var brightness = 0.34 * data[i] + 0.5 * data[i + 1] + 0.16 * data[i + 2];
                // red
                data[i] = brightness;
              // green
                data[i + 1] = brightness;
                // blue
              data[i + 2] = brightness;
              }
            /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

            /* ~~~~~ This part counts the number of dark pixels ~~~~~ */
            var count=0;
            for(var j=0;j<data.length;j+=4){
                if(data[j]<200 && data[j+1]<200 && data[j+2]<200){
                count+=4;
            }
        }
        /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

        /* ~~~~~ If the number of dark pixels are 80% of total pixels, then assume image to be dark ~~~~~ */
        if(count>=(data.length*0.8)){
            document.getElementById('content').style.color="white";
        }else{
            document.getElementById('content').style.color="black";
        }
       /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

       /* ~~~~~ Print total pixel and counted dark pixels ~~~~~ */
        document.getElementById('dataLength').innerHTML ="Data length"+data.length+" Data length/2 "+(data.length/2);
        document.getElementById('blackCount').innerHTML ="Black Count"+count;
       /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

       // Draw grayscale image on cavas
        context.putImageData(imageData, x, y);

  }
  setInterval(loop,2000);

  </script>  

</body>
</html>
```